# Hotreloading discord python bot in Docker

Tags: python, docker, reload, discord, discord.py

I want to dockerize my discord bot written in python for developement process but I can't get it done. In docker-compose it is like that right now:

```
discord_bot:
  build: ./discord
  volumes:
    - ./discord:/usr/src/discord
  depends_on:
    - mongo
    - node
```

Is there a way I can hot reload this code while still using discord.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to auto-reload on code change for local development, what you have is mostly correct. The one thing you're missing is launching the main process via some sort of file watcher. You could use [nodemon with python](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/c1211876113732cbff78eb1ae10483eaaf77e5cf/lib/config/defaults.js), or find some equivalent for python specifically.

Changes you need to make:

1. You're build image needs to contain some sort of file watcher. You could use Nodemon for this (even for python , or use some python equivalent)
2. You should override the default command of the image to launch via your file watcher.

   ```
   discord_bot:
     build: ./discord     <--- Should include file watcher executable (nodemon or some python equivalent)
     command: nodemon /usr/src/discord/index.js  <--- add this line
     volumes:
       - ./discord:/usr/src/discord
     depends_on:
       - mongo
       - node
   ```